# PHP is there any way to optimize array_unshift with more than 200000 executions?

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

i have two files with data in `json` format:

**New_data.json**

```
[{
  "AUDCAD": {
    "MN": {
      "t": [1435708800],
      "o": [0.9652],
      "h": [0.9653],
      "l": [0.94],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [4040241]
    },
    "W1": {
      "t": [1437264000],
      "o": [0.9528],
      "h": [0.9634],
      "l": [0.948],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [1052713]
    },
    "D1": {
      "t": [1437696000],
      "o": [0.95],
      "h": [0.9522],
      "l": [0.9486],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [158491]
    },
    "H4": {
      "t": [1437739200],
      "o": [0.9501],
      "h": [0.9522],
      "l": [0.9496],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [23012]
    },
    "H1": {
      "t": [1437750000],
      "o": [0.9513],
      "h": [0.9515],
      "l": [0.9505],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [2015]
    },
    "M30": {
      "t": [1437750000],
      "o": [0.9513],
      "h": [0.9515],
      "l": [0.9505],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [2015]
    },
    "M15": {
      "t": [1437750900],
      "o": [0.9513],
      "h": [0.9514],
      "l": [0.9505],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [757]
    },
    "M5": {
      "t": [1437751200],
      "o": [0.9507],
      "h": [0.9512],
      "l": [0.9506],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [159]
    },
    "M1": {
      "t": [1437751260],
      "o": [0.951],
      "h": [0.9512],
      "l": [0.9507],
      "c": [0.9508],
      "v": [33]
    }
  },
  "AUDCHF": {
    "MN": {
      "t": [1435708800],
      "o": [0.7226],
      "h": [0.7262],
      "l": [0.6949],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [1521567]
    },
    "W1": {
      "t": [1437264000],
      "o": [0.7064],
      "h": [0.7129],
      "l": [0.6973],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [376787]
    },
    "D1": {
      "t": [1437696000],
      "o": [0.7007],
      "h": [0.7032],
      "l": [0.6973],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [53293]
    },
    "H4": {
      "t": [1437739200],
      "o": [0.7001],
      "h": [0.7014],
      "l": [0.6986],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [7849]
    },
    "H1": {
      "t": [1437750000],
      "o": [0.7009],
      "h": [0.7012],
      "l": [0.7004],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [580]
    },
    "M30": {
      "t": [1437750000],
      "o": [0.7009],
      "h": [0.7012],
      "l": [0.7004],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [580]
    },
    "M15": {
      "t": [1437750900],
      "o": [0.7009],
      "h": [0.7012],
      "l": [0.7007],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [154]
    },
    "M5": {
      "t": [1437751200],
      "o": [0.7009],
      "h": [0.7012],
      "l": [0.7009],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [24]
    },
    "M1": {
      "t": [1437751260],
      "o": [0.7011],
      "h": [0.7012],
      "l": [0.701],
      "c": [0.7011],
      "v": [9]
    }
  }
}]
```

**Old_data.json**

```
[{
  "AUDCAD": {
    "MN": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "W1": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "D1": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "H4": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "H1": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "M30": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "M15": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "M5": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "M1": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    }
  },
  "AUDCHF": {
    "MN": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "W1": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "D1": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "H4": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "H1": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "M30": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "M15": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "M5": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    },
    "M1": {
      "t": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "o": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "h": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "l": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "c": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
      "v": [1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234]
    }
  }
}]
```

Basically, I need to update the **old_data.json** file with the latest data from **new_data.json**.

But these new data should prepend to the beginning of **old_data.json**, so the final json file "**data_updated.json**" looks like this:

```
[{"AUDCAD" : { 
               "MN": {
                           //New_data |  Old_data
                       "t":[1435708800,1234,1234,1234,1234],
                       "o":[0.9652,1234,1234,1234,1234],
                       "h":[0.9653,1234,1234,1234,1234],
                       "l":[0.94,1234,1234,1234,1234],
                       "c":[0.9508,1234,1234,1234,1234],
                       "v":[4040241,1234,1234,1234,1234]
                     }
              },
   ....
 }]
```

To perform this action, I'm using `array_unshift` on each position of the `array`, my code looks like this:

```
//First I open the json files using jsonDB.class.php of Straussn's
$new_data = $db->selectAll("new_data.json");
$old_data = $db->selectAll("old_data.json");

foreach ($new_data as $j) {
    array_unshift($old_data[0]["AUDCAD"]["M1"]['t'], $j["AUDCAD"]["M1"]["t"][0]);
    array_unshift($old_data[0]["AUDCAD"]["M1"]['o'], $j["AUDCAD"]["M1"]["o"][0]);
    array_unshift($old_data[0]["AUDCAD"]["M1"]['h'], $j["AUDCAD"]["M1"]["h"][0]);
    array_unshift($old_data[0]["AUDCAD"]["M1"]['l'], $j["AUDCAD"]["M1"]["l"][0]);
    array_unshift($old_data[0]["AUDCAD"]["M1"]['c'], $j["AUDCAD"]["M1"]["c"][0]);
    array_unshift($old_data[0]["AUDCAD"]["M1"]['v'], $j["AUDCAD"]["M1"]["v"][0]);

//I repeat this spagheti code for each symbol "AUD / ..." each time "M1,M5, M15..." and each data "t, o, h, l, c, v". 
//I must repeat this 200000 times.
}
```

I know it's totally absurd write/repeat +200000 lines of code to perform this simple action, but I'm beginner in programming and i can't find a practical way to perform this action. 
Maybe you can help me on what I can do to optimize this action, learn more and improve my code.

Thanks to everyone for your time.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php - IKR

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix  array_merge_recursive  append the values to the end, I need to do it at the beginning. Maybe I can use array_reverse on values to correct. Thanks!

Comment: Change the order, append to the end, is prepend to the other.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix  tried it but changing the order removes data from the second array.

Comment: 200000 records.. think a json might not be the best  persistance store for

Comment: @Orangepill Yes, but at the moment it is the most fast and flexible database that I found [JsonDB.class -Github](https://github.com/strzlee/JsonDB.class.php) Mysql is too slow for my purpose and did not know any other options that may improve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix There was a mistake with my data, it's funny because before asking the question and write my spaghetti code I had tried with `array_merge_recursive` (even with inverted arrays) without success. However, helped me to find the error in my data that caused the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried,

```
array_merge_recursive( $newdata, $olddata );
```

Or

```
array_merge_recursive( $olddata, $newdata );
```

Which comes first the chicken or the egg, me I am to lazy to figure it out.

Comment: *"Which comes first the chicken or the egg"* - The rooster.

Answer (score 0):

array_slice might do the trick for you.

```
array_splice( $data, 0, 0, $newData);
```

This will update `$data` and insert `$newData` at position 0.